# Flow unable to use decision element properly

Tags: recordtriggeredflow

[image][image]i am trying to create a flow for our org ,so as per requirement we have 4 checkboxes to a record and for every checkbox marked or in combination it should send the email to that particular group(checkbox people)
for example :
4 checkboxes
arch req
bu req
state req
default

when a case is created with arch required checkbox to true then it should send the arch related email alert
and in combination like  arch req ,bu req then it should send two email alerts arch req,bu req ..go on if all 4 marked then 4 email alerts should go ...

i tried creating seperate flows for each group it wokred for me but when i am trying to create all in one flow using decision it is sending to only first outcome mentinoed ,,,not at all passing to other elements

[image]

Comment: Please add the screenshot of the Decision element

Comment: Your flow will only execute one of the email alerts, the first one for which the condition is true. Look at how after sending you "end" the flow. You need to break this into a sequence of decisions that chain through, sending the email alert for each option (or not sending) then moving on to the next option. Effectively you will have 4 decisions with the one branch going through an Email Alert and another that does nothing, and where both branches join up again at the following decision (or the end of the flow). Remember to handle failures too.

Comment: @apz i have added decision screenshot ..

Comment: @phil W:how to break into sequence of decisions can you help me to understand

Comment: tried to vhange mentioned like above screenshot but still going to only one condition

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this into a cascade of conditions, where each either does or does not send the required email. I've illustrated the flow structure for the first two decisions here, you need to have this with a sequence of 4 decisions, each deciding on whether to send the relevant email:

[image: Cascading conditions and email sending]