# Facing issue while creating a dependency flow

Tags: community, visual-workflow, visual-flows, pkce-flow-salesforce

[image][image: flow created]requirement : if my picklist and subpicklist has values  and my flow is dependent on checkboxes to trigger email alerts
let say
picklist : value1
subPicklist: Value1
checkbox1 : true
checkbox2: true
checkbox3: false
Then the flow will be triggered and sends two email alerts on basis of two checkboxes .. and when i try to update the checkbox3 in the created record then it should trigger email alert related to checkbox3
so my flow is creating as expected at the time of creating the record
butwhile updating the record it is sending all the email alerts at once which is not expected . unable to figure out how to change my flow
i have used cascading the decision as mentinoed here [Flow unable to use decision element properly](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/400791/flow-unable-to-use-decision-element-properly)
FYI i tried to add ischange function to the flow aswell but facing the issue while updating the 3rd checkbox .. it is the same that i am receiving all the email alerts when i have updated the checkbox3 .
The pre-condtion is created or updated becuase it should be working for all the conditions create and updated aswell ... any thoughts please help me

Answer (score 0):

seeing what you have as your starting conditions and your decision criteria might help show what could be causing the issue for you on update, but hopefully this helps.

I would approach it as with simple criteria and I just used some checkbox fields I had handy to use as demonstration. Note the `A record is created or updated`, `Any Condition Is Met (OR)`, and `Only when a record is updated...`.
[image]

If this is the same you already have I would test using `Every time a record...`. This will increase the number the flow has to run but shouldn't continue to send email alerts if your decision criteria is clear.

With this in place you can have your decision criteria set similarly to below.
This will make sure that New records are considered rather than relying on a prior value by using a simple ISNEW() formula flow resource.
[image]

This is just my personal approach.

Comment: flow is considering all the feilds which are already available as changed ,hence sending all  the email alerts at once .. unbale to handle the update record

Comment: @rizu it would be helpful to see the decision criteria you have to better understand what issue you're having